# birational map P1

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have the following problem to prove that $V(x_0^3-x_2x_1^2)\subset\mathbb P_k^2 $, where $k$ algebraically closed field, is birational to $\mathbb P_k^1$.

I'm a beginner at this stuff, so someone tell me please if I'm following the right track.
I thought to prove that the coordinate rings of $V(x_0^3-x_2)$ and $\mathbb A^1_k$  are isomorphic. Is this correct and enough?

Comment: I think you meant $\Bbb A^1_k$

Comment: Yes, I did indeed. Thank you, now I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: As you suggested, $V(x_0^3-x_2) = V(x_0^3 - x_2x_1^2) \cap \{x_1\neq 0\}$ is an open set of $V(x_0^3-x_2)$. Now use that two varieties are birrational if you can find isomorphic open sets in them.